# Connect to mssql from python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect mssql from python. For this I am using below code but looks like something is wrong with the connection. Can anyone help me ?

```
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc 

##conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native client 11.0};server=localhost;database=Nifty;trusted_connection=yes;')

engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://localhost/Nifty?driver=SQL+Server+Native+client+11.0?Trusted_Connection=yes')

engine.execute('select  top 2 * from [dbo].ABC')
```

I am getting below error

```
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Comment: Try `mssql+pyodbc://@localhost/Nifty/? …`

Comment: tried ````sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@localhost/Nifty/?driver=SQL+Server+Native+client+11.0?Trusted_Connection=yes')```` . But still getting same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls first check if you have specified driver in connection:

> control panel>Systems and Security>Administrative Tools.>ODBC Data Sources>System DSN tab>Add

and then try :

```
engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://localhost/Nifty?driver=SQL+Server+Native+client+11.0?Trusted_Connection=yes',echo = True)
```

[official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html)

---

or, You can use some of the Solutions below:

**Solution 1**

define driver like this :

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=serverName\instanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

and then put it in pyodbc.connect(" here ") and run it using cursor, [see this](https://datadiaries.dev/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc)

---

**Solution 2**

With Windows Authentication Without using DSN's

```
engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/db')
```

---

**Solution 3**
using urllib

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=dagger;"
                                 "DATABASE=test;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```